# Icebreak or Breaking Wodden Planks using cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

Is there any way in cocos2d-x where i can cut the sprite in to two parts or may be some animation I can do in cocos2dx by which I can show the breaking of ice and wooden planks in two parts (Like it happens in kungfu and karate). The application is about kungfu techniques when user swipe on things It should break the ice nd wooden planks etc ...

Anything sort of that without using physics ?

The concern is wherever user swipes from that point the sprites should get cut ..Otherwise i would have taken an individual animation of breaking the ice

Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to approach this is to define a custom CCNode that has an array of CCSprites. Fill the array with different parts of the ice/plank and position them so they appear as one piece. Define the bounding box of the CCNode so it's the sum of all your pieces and use the swipe against the position to detect a hit.